# Store values of Ms access database into an array

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I want to store selected values of an access table in an array. I'm using oledbconnection. For example, I have a students table in course database. And the table has dob values in it. I want to run a query that gets dob values and stores them in an array. Also I'm using vb.net

Comment: I would suggest you've got a bit of reading to do.  Perhaps start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: @Hursey Why the DataAdapter?

Comment: @Mary Well, IMO DataAdapters are pretty handy tools when it comes DB interactions, while I admit not completely required, still a very handy tool that does a fair amount of the heavy lifting for you

Comment: If you're going to use a DataAdapter, you might as well use a TableAdapter and get VS to do all the lifting

Comment: Retrieving a list of discrete values, like dates of birth *isn't normally very useful*, by the way, because you lose any knowledge of whose birthdays they are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code assumes

- the name of the table is Students
- the name of the field is DOB
- the type of the DOB field is Date

I don't know how much you know about data access with ADO or Linq but please try to research what your don't understand. It is fine to use other peoples code. Just try to understand what it is doing.

```
Private Function GetDOB() As Date()
    Dim strSql = "Select DOB From Students"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connectionstring"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim DOBs = dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Date)(0)).ToArray
    Return DOBs
End Function
```

Comment: That code would be a boatload shorter with a DataAdapter and a single line with a TableAdapter

Comment: @CaiusJard The number of lines of code may not be germane. Both would require a connection object. Probably a TableAdapter creates a command and reader internally. A DataAdapter is a heavier object with additional functionality not used here.

Comment: DataTable.Load uses an adapter... A DataAdapter will make its own connection if handed a connection string

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you. I see now that Load uses a LoadAdapter which inherits DataAdapter.